# Restore textfield's default value when user clicks the reset button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the textfields to return to their default value when the user clicks the Reset button.

All it does now when the user clicks the Reset button is replacing the user's text with ''.

How can I do it by using pure JavaScript (no jQuery)?

**HTML:**

```
<p>Type the first number</p>
<input id="first" type="text" placeholder="First Number" />
<p>Type the second number</p>
<input id="second" type="text" placeholder="Second Number" />
<button id="aButton">Apply</button>
<button id="rButton">Reset</button>
<div id="add"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
        var aButton = document.getElementById("aButton");
        aButton.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);

        var rButton = document.getElementById("rButton");
        rButton.addEventListener("click", buttonResetHandler, false);

    };

...

function buttonResetHandler(evetInfo) {

        document.getElementById("first").innerText = '';
        document.getElementById("second").innerText = '';

    }
```

Comment: `<button type="reset">Reset</button>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`innerText` is an *invalid* property that is implemented in IE browsers and is used for setting/getting text content of non-form elements, if the values should be set as default, you can use [**`defaultValue`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) property:

```
var a = document.getElementById("first"),
    b = document.getElementById("second");
a.value = a.defaultValue;
b.value = b.defaultValue;
```

If you want to reset all the form elements, you can use [**`.reset()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) method of DOM `HTMLFormElement` object:

```
document.forms["myForm"].reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. location.reload(); // reloads the page
2. history.go(0); // deletes the history
3. But if you need to preserve some values inside of the page then reassign the values in the function again. To reassign, write the variable (declare in `let` to change later) again in the `function` and change the `textContent` again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace,

```
document.getElementById("first").innerText
```

With,

```
document.getElementById("first").value
```

Example:

```
<input id="txtBox" type="text" value="lama">
<input type="button" value="reset lama" onclick='document.getElementById("txtBox").value="lama2";'>
```

Comment: add to the button the event.  <button id="resetBtn" onclick='buttonResetHandler();'>Reset</button>

Answer (score -1):

create an init function that sets the default values for each input, then you can call that:

```
function initializeInputs() {
    document.getElementById("first").value = '';
    document.getElementById("second").value= '';
}

function buttonResetHandler(e) {
    initializeInputs();
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("first").innerText gives an error. And I think thats not what he asked.

Comment: The above just replaces the user's input with something else. What I want is to remove the user's input and restore the default value (First Number/Second Number).